# How to flatten a seq to a string and build it back in Scala?

Tags: scala

How to flatten a `Seq` like `("a", "b", "c")` to `"a,b,c"` in Scala?

And how to build one back from a comma separated `String`? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first, try:

```
val seq = Seq("a", "b", "c")
val string = seq.mkString(",")
```

For the second:

```
val parsed = string.split(",")
```

which returns an `Array`, so if it must be a `Seq` then:

```
val parsed = string.split(",").toSeq
```